# What does . ~/.bashrc command do?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I was viewing my .bash_profile file, and I saw this written inside a block of if statement:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       . ~/.bashrc
```

Can someone explain what the second line is actually doing?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182282/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second line “sources” the `.bashrc` script; that means it loads and executes its contents in the same shell context. The result is the same as putting the contents of `.bashrc` in `.bash_profile`.

This statement is useful because the two files are used in different contexts: `.bash_profile` is executed when `bash` starts as a login shell, whereas  `.bashrc` is executed when `bash` is started as a non-login interactive shell. Including `.bashrc` in `.bash_profile` allows it to be the single place for you to add customisation which you want to have in all interactive shells.

If `.bashrc` wasn’t sourced using `.`, its execution would spawn a new shell just for the duration, and its effects would be lost immediately.

Comment: Can . be used for sourcing all kinds of files?

Comment: As long as the files are shell scripts, yes! For example it’s handy to build up a library of shell functions. You can see it used in many init scripts (in `/etc/init.d/`) to load the LSB functions (`/lib/lsb/init-functions`) or to load external configuration files (such as those in `/etc/default`).